# cocoa:when I called toggleFullScreen method,how to back?

Tags: cocoa, fullscreen, exit

how to make the window mode exit full screen mode?

I know pressing "esc" to exit,I want to know,which method has been called when press "esc"?

any ideas?

Thanks,
Blues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toggleFullScreen:` will be called.  Toggle in apple's sense means that it will switch in or out depending on the current state.  So if the window was in full screen, calling `toggleFullScreen:` will take the window out of full screen mode.  Quoting the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
toggleFullScreen:
Taken the window into or out of fullscreen mode,
```